# 500: internal server error while trying to call a REST api from C# console

Tags: c#, salesforce

I m trying to generate a token from salesforce api with oauth. I m using this token to retreive data and then perform put request for each object. However, the web response is showing an unhandled exception saying "500:Internal server error" while i m trying to generate a token. I need to pass content type and accept in header params and other params in body.

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string response = Post("https://xx-dev.cs15.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(response);
            string accessToken = data.access_token;


        }
        //POST to generate token.
        private static string Post(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string body = "client_id=43nmbmn43534y98jh_3yQty7vm3CqYMvrSdfdsfFDSGFW7kNYk_bWxmhTaY5KT&client_secret=123456789&grant_type=password&username=user@username.com.test&password=TestPassword";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();//**I'm getting the error here**
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            return responseFromServer;
        }
```

Headers:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO6zD.png);
[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhf7c.png)

Comment: A 500 reponse usually indicates there is something wrong with your request. Try looking at the raw response in a proxy like e.g. Fiddler to see if there is any extra information which will help you.

Comment: Provide More detail about the error that you find as suggested by @stuartd

Comment: @Jr Dev, I updated my answer below. Also I forgot to mention, I wonder if your Salesforce configuration is set up for API requests for the account you're using, in case this is the first time this account has been used to integrate with API.

Comment: Could you add what headers are present when you invoke the service through your application versus the headers in Postman?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the content your are passing in the body should be in the URL. The [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_verify_dotnet_rest.htm) suggests building your `HttpWebRequest` like this:

```
string strContent = "grant_type=password" +
"&client_id=" + consumerKey +
"&client_secret=" + consumerSecret +
"&username=" + acctName +
"&password=" + acctPw;

string urlStr = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?" + strContent;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlStr) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I spent a lot of time trying to get it working with the content in the body like you have it, but I kept getting "(400) Bad Request" as the response. I'm not sure why you were originally getting "500:Internal server error" back; I kept getting the "(400) Bad Request" response back using the exact same code you were using.

The code example in the Developer Documentation is working for me. There are some REST wrappers available if you would like to try that; most are available as NuGet packages. See [SalesforceSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp). It may be worth considering as it would likely reduce the amount of code you have to write and be less tedious.

Here is my source code which I copied from the [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_verify_dotnet_rest.htm) if you would like to replace it with your credentials and see if it works for you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json; 

namespace VerifyRESTTest
{
    class Program
    {
        // Class used for serializing the OAuth JSON response
        [DataContract]
        public class OAuthUsernamePasswordResponse
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string instance_url { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string issued_at { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string signature { get; set; }
        }

        private static string accessToken = "";
        private static string instanceUrl = "";

        private static void login()
        {
            string acctName = "########@gmail.com";
            string acctPw = "##############";
            string consumerKey = "###############################################";
            string consumerSecret = "#################";

            // Just for testing the developer environment, we use the simple username-password OAuth flow.
            // In production environments, make sure to use a stronger OAuth flow, such as User-Agent
            string strContent = "grant_type=password" + 
                "&client_id=" + consumerKey + 
                "&client_secret=" + consumerSecret + 
                "&username=" + acctName + 
                "&password=" + acctPw;

            string urlStr = "https://############-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?" + strContent;

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlStr) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";

            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        throw new Exception(String.Format(
                            "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                            response.StatusCode,
                            response.StatusDescription));

                    // Parse the JSON response and extract the access token and instance URL
                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OAuthUsernamePasswordResponse));
                    OAuthUsernamePasswordResponse objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as OAuthUsernamePasswordResponse;
                    accessToken = objResponse.access_token;
                    instanceUrl = objResponse.instance_url;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            login(); 
            if (accessToken != "") 
            {
                // display some current login settings
                Console.Write("Instance URL: " + instanceUrl + "\n");
                Console.Write("Access Token: " + accessToken + "\n");
                Console.Write("Press any key to continue:\n");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some things to consider: Since you ended up getting a "(400) Bad Request" when you initially tried the example code as opposed to the "500:Internal server error", the "HTTP 400" is more specific and usually indicates a syntax error, so it might be worth trying the example method again and making sure something wasn't mistyped, and your security token, site key, client secret, username, and password are correct, and that you appended your security token to the end of your password.

**Edit 2**

See how SalesforceSharp authenticates with Salesforce in [Line 93](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp/blob/master/src/SalesforceSharp/Security/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFlow.cs#L93). They are using RestSharp, which is available as a NuGet package.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en&type=0

Comment: @L.B, I'm referencing C# code provided on the Salesforce Developer Documentation (see the link in my answer) to obtain the access token. I don't see what's wrong with that.

Comment: Tried using the changed url, but now i m getting a error response of 400:Bad request

Comment: @Poosh I have tried using the code in the link with my specific api. But i got the same error. I tried to pass the same request using postman and got a successful response, I have compared RAW data in both cases using fiddler, i see that header values are not being passed incase of c# application. Any help with that would be really appreciated. C# newbie here.